# "Write out a prescription" vs. "make out a prescription"

Tags: word-choice, semantics, collocation

Are "write out a prescription" and "make out a prescription" used more or less interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are, though "write out a prescription" is more common, as evidenced by a Google search and an [Ngram graph](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=write%20out%20a%20prescription,make%20out%20a%20prescription&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although be  careful - "make up a prescription" would be to supply the drugs listed on it.

Once upon a time it would be to actually make up, i.e. *produce*, the medicine required in the pharmacy - now of course it's just to sell the correct boxes of pills.

Comment: +1, but there are still "compounding pharmacies" that will actually produce the medicine in proper form or mixture. Your average Walgreens, CVS or Rite-Aid, however, do much as you describe; they count out the prescribed number of the correct pill into a bottle and hand it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

"Write out" carries more of a connotation of the physical act of marking a scrip sheet, whereas "make out" gestures a bit more toward the possibly metaphysical act of bestowing the prescription itself.

(I would say that's a slim enough shade of difference to be considered 'interchangeable')

Comment: I wouldn't even go as far as to say that there is a difference.  In all cases, you have to "write out" the prescription in order to "make out" the prescription.

Comment: I dunno, don't they have digital prescriptions in some civilized countries?

Comment: Even there, the difference isn't between physically"marking" and metaphysically "bestowing".